# MySQL - How can I make a function atomic?

Tags: mysql, database

I have this function in my DB

```
CREATE FUNCTION BookBed (pPaciente varchar(255),
                                pHospital bigint(20)) RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
DECLARE NumLeitosDisponiveis INT;
DECLARE vReservaOK  BOOLEAN;
DECLARE dt TIMESTAMP;

 SET dt = (Select now());
 SET NumLeitosDisponiveis = (SELECT AVAILABLEBEDCOUNT FROM HOSPITAL WHERE ID = pHospital); 


 IF((SELECT NumLeitosDisponiveis) > 0) THEN 
 BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;

  INSERT INTO RESERVATION(PERSON, HOSPITAL, DATE) VALUES (pPaciente, pHospital, dt);

  UPDATE HOSPITAL
    SET AVAILABLEBEDCOUNT = AVAILABLEBEDCOUNT - 1 
    WHERE ID = pHospital;

    SET vReservaOk = true;

    commit;
 END;
  ELSE 
    SET vReservaOk = false;     
  END IF;


 RETURN vReservaOK;

END;
```

In the if part of my if-else statement, I would like to perform all the operations in a atomic way.
I wanted to use the START TRANSACTION command, but they are disallowed in functions and I couldn't find any other command to perform it.

Are functions atomic by default?
If not, is there any way I can implement it?

Thanks,
Oscar

**EDIT: And if I have to use a function, is it possible to have transactions?**

Comment: When you say "atomic", what do you mean?

Comment: @Olaf: "atomic" means "guaranteed to happen without interruption from other processes". Like, you know the database cannot be updated between one select statement and the next.

Comment: You will be running your function in a transaction context. Whatever changes are happening in the context of other transactions, they are not visible in your function and do not affect its work. A database transaction is atomic by definition.

Comment: You can always manually [lock tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a stored procedure with an output parameter for returning the operation status.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE BookBed (
    pPaciente varchar(255),
    pHospital bigint(20),
    OUT oReservaOK boolean)
BEGIN
    DECLARE NumLeitosDisponiveis INT;
    DECLARE dt TIMESTAMP;

    SET dt = (Select now());
    SET NumLeitosDisponiveis =
        SELECT AVAILABLEBEDCOUNT FROM HOSPITAL WHERE ID = pHospital; 

    IF((SELECT NumLeitosDisponiveis) > 0) THEN 
    BEGIN
        START TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO RESERVATION(PERSON, HOSPITAL, DATE)
            VALUES (pPaciente, pHospital, dt);

        UPDATE HOSPITAL
            SET AVAILABLEBEDCOUNT = AVAILABLEBEDCOUNT - 1 
        WHERE ID = pHospital;

        SET oReservaOk = true;

        commit;
    END;
    ELSE 
        SET oReservaOk = false;     
    END IF;
END//
```

If you are having trouble calling the stored procedure using Hibernate, then move the transaction logic to Hibernate.  That is, start, commit or rollback the transaction using Hibernate constructs.

**EDIT**
Transactions require using the InnoDB engine as @bobobobo notes on the comments.

Comment: I had problems because then I am having problems to call it using hibernate and get the return value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497080/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-using-hibernate 
Is there any way to use transactions on a function?

Comment: Why would you want to start a transaction in the stored procedure? Is transaction the procedure is called in "not atomic enough"?

Comment: @Oscar, no, transactions are not supported inside functions in MySQL. @Olaf, the question of the OP was how to use a transaction inside a function, which in MySQL is not possible; so the option is to use a stored procedure instead.

Comment: Note you have to be using InnoDB tables for this to work. ["MyISAM does not support transactions and probably never will."](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,68686,69229#msg-69229)