# How to call a stored procedure using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am having some problems with hibernate and MySQL. I've been reading but I am getting even more confused, so I imagine you could help me understand what I should do next.

I have a MySQL database in which I added this Stored Procedure (thanks to the Stack Overflow people)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BookBed (
OUT oReservaOK boolean,
pPaciente varchar(255),
pHospital bigint(20))
BEGIN
 DECLARE NumLeitosDisponiveis INT;
 DECLARE dt TIMESTAMP;

SET dt = (Select now());
SET NumLeitosDisponiveis = (SELECT AVAILABLEBEDCOUNT FROM HOSPITAL WHERE ID = pHospital); 

IF((SELECT NumLeitosDisponiveis) > 0) THEN 
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO RESERVATION(PERSON, HOSPITAL, DATE)
        VALUES (pPaciente, pHospital, dt);

    UPDATE HOSPITAL
        SET AVAILABLEBEDCOUNT = AVAILABLEBEDCOUNT - 1 
    WHERE ID = pHospital;

    SET oReservaOk = true;

    commit;
END;
ELSE 
    SET oReservaOk = false;     
END IF;
END
```

I've read somewhere that calling functions and procedures using hibernate would be very similar. Then I found (coincidently also [in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703351/how-to-call-a-oracle-function-from-hibernate-with-return-parameter)), the code to execute a function using from my java application using Hibernate:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
        @Override
          public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call " + functionName + "(?,?,?)  }");
            call.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.BOOLEAN ); // or whatever it is
            call.setString(2, param1);
            call.setLong(3, param2);
            call.registerOutParameter( 4, Types.BOOLEAN ); // or whatever it is
            call.execute();
            DatabaseManager.this.setResult(call.getBoolean(1)); // propagate this back to enclosing class
          }
        });
```

I tried to use it but I get different kinds of errors (it depends how I setup the parameters). At the current point in time, I am getting a "No value specified for parameter 3" error because I registered an output parameter.
I've searched for more information but I am getting confused because the websites have different approaches and many links to the documentation are broken (links to JBoss web site).

I've read I have to return a cursor as the first out parameter. I am searching the way to do it in MySQL. (But I've read this is an indication that your design is bad)
What should I do? I am completely lost...
How can I solve it? Should I change the procedure to return my value in some other way?

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the signature of your stored procedure and the way you call it. You have to call it as "call BookBed(?, ?, ?)". Also note that it takes only 3 parameters, not 4.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers here and in the other question. The first parameter is the out parameter, as I could understand from the link I posted in the question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703351/how-to-call-a-oracle-function-from-hibernate-with-return-parameter) it has to be used to get the return value.
I will use a function, as I was doing, and I hope I can get the things working again.
Thanks once more